# How to create gson format for json map of date keys?

Tags: android, json, date, kotlin, gson

I have the Problem, can't creating a format class to get json from file with gson.

My json looks like:

```
{
  "2019-08-01": {
    "foo": [
      "2019-08-01 03:31:00Z",
      "2019-08-01 05:36:00Z"
    ],
    "baa": [
      "2019-08-01 05:36:00Z",
      "2019-08-01 13:27:00Z"
    ],
  }
}
```

and the kotlin code looks so:

```
class PFormat {
    val days: DateTimesFormat? = null
}

class DateTimesFormat {
    val dateTime: Map<String, List<String>>? = null
}

private var gson = Gson()

val pFormatJsonfile: File = File("/data/user/0/com.example.blabla/app_flutter/appSettings.json")
val bufferedReader: BufferedReader = prayersFormatJsonfile.bufferedReader()
val stringFromJsonFile = bufferedReader.use { it.readText() }
var pDataAsJson = gson.fromJson(stringFromJsonFile, PFormat::class.java)

print(pDataAsJson.days)
```

Comment: Try with GsonBuilder().create() for creating gson object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might help

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

use this method like

```
try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("formules");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> m_li;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("formule"));
            String formula_value = jo_inside.getString("formule");
            String url_value = jo_inside.getString("url");

            //Add your values in your `ArrayList` as below:
            m_li = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m_li.put("formule", formula_value);
            m_li.put("url", url_value);

            formList.add(m_li);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```